# mongoimport .csv into existing collection and database

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I have a database that contains a collection that has documents in it already. Now I'm trying to insert another .csv into the same database and collection. for example one document in the db.collection has:

```
Name: Bob
Age: 25
```

and an entry from the csv im tying to upload is like this:

```
Name: Bob
Age:27
```

How can I import the new csv without replacing any documents, just adding to the database so that both entries will be in the database.collection?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `mongoimport`, take a look at the `--mode` [option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#options).

> With `--mode merge`, `mongoimport` enables you to merge fields from a new
>   record with an existing document in the database. Documents that do
>   not match an existing document in the database are inserted as usual.

Comment: I don't want to merge fields

Comment: In that case, you may want to use the `insert` option. Your use case didn't describe how to handle _id, so I had to guess. In any case, the `--mode` option controls what happens when there are duplicates found. The [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#options) should help you determine whether to use `insert`, `upsert`, or `merge`.